# react native app crashes on iOS on launch

Tags: ios, react-native, crash, testflight

After a small update to my app in TestFlight, it crashes every time I open it. This happens for all the different devices i've tried.

Uploading the build to Android works and the app works fine without any crashes.

I didn't make any significant changes to the app, other than adding 2 small packages and some styling changes.

I'm not really sure what the issue is or how to interpret the crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: FE17E0D9-BD0F-451C-853A-D2877DE78344
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,8
Process:             TeachAssist [22596]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/181A550D-D6D7-47C6-AAF9-FC6F91846389/TeachAssist.app/TeachAssist
Identifier:          io.github.teachassistapp
Version:             1.0.5 (1)
AppStoreTools:       13E500
AppVariant:          1:iPhone11,8:15
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           io.github.teachassistapp [2285]

Date/Time:           2022-04-25 13:18:15.6022 -0400
Launch Time:         2022-04-25 13:18:15.2986 -0400
OS Version:          iPhone OS 15.4.1 (19E258)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    4.03.02
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  4

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1c3671d78 __exceptionPreprocess + 220 (NSException.m:200)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1dc2d6734 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   TeachAssist                     0x102fb6170 RCTFatal + 668 (RCTAssert.m:146)
3   TeachAssist                     0x103033944 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatal:stack:exceptionId:suppressRedBox:] + 600 (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:89)
4   TeachAssist                     0x103034300 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportException:] + 1532 (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:164)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x1c35fa614 __invoking___ + 148
6   CoreFoundation                  0x1c3618100 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 468 (NSForwarding.m:3378)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x1c364f13c -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 80 (NSForwarding.m:3475)
8   TeachAssist                     0x102fe70e0 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 460 (RCTModuleMethod.mm:584)
9   TeachAssist                     0x102fe9578 facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&, int, (anonymous namespace)::SchedulingContext) + 540 (RCTNativeModule.mm:181)
10  TeachAssist                     0x102fe91b0 operator() + 56 (RCTNativeModule.mm:103)
11  TeachAssist                     0x102fe91b0 invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int) + 100 (RCTNativeModule.mm:95)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x1c32d6e68 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1517)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x1c32d8a2c _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x1c32e0124 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 668 (inline_internal.h:2622)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x1c32e0c80 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 392 (queue.c:3944)
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x1c32eb500 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648 (queue.c:6732)
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2345f60bc _pthread_wqthread + 288 (pthread.c:2599)
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2345f5e5c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fafda4e0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fafdab24 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c35df820 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c35e3cac __CFRunLoopRun + 1180 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c35f76b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   GraphicsServices                0x00000001df691374 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2200)
6   UIKitCore                       0x00000001c5f5ce88 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100 (UIApplication.m:3511)
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001c5cde5ec UIApplicationMain + 364 (UIApplication.m:5064)
8   TeachAssist                     0x0000000102f054f4 main + 88 (main.m:7)
9   dyld                            0x000000010328dce4 start + 520 (dyldMain.cpp:879)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345f5e54 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345f5e54 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345f5e54 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fafe0b78 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345fc3bc pthread_kill + 268 (pthread.c:1668)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001ce75451c abort + 168 (abort.c:118)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001dc3e1b7c abort_message + 132 (abort_message.cpp:78)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001dc3d19c4 demangling_terminate_handler() + 336 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:71)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001dc2dcc88 _objc_terminate() + 144 (objc-exception.mm:701)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001dc3e0f18 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001dc3e0eb4 std::terminate() + 64 (cxa_handlers.cpp:88)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c32d8a40 _dispatch_client_callout + 40 (object.m:563)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c32e0124 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 668 (inline_internal.h:2622)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c32e0c80 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 392 (queue.c:3944)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c32eb500 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648 (queue.c:6732)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345f60bc _pthread_wqthread + 288 (pthread.c:2599)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345f5e5c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345f5e54 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6 name:
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fafda4e0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fafdab24 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c35df820 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c35e3cac __CFRunLoopRun + 1180 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c35f76b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001c4dde414 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 236 (NSRunLoop.m:373)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001c4e1fcac -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 92 (NSRunLoop.m:420)
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001c5ed6fb0 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 524 (UIEventFetcher.m:1167)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001c4e2e55c __NSThread__start__ + 808 (NSThread.m:972)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345f69ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345f5e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 7 name:
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fafda4e0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fafdab24 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c35df820 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c35e3cac __CFRunLoopRun + 1180 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c35f76b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   TeachAssist                     0x0000000102fc8970 +[RCTCxxBridge runRunLoop] + 264 (RCTCxxBridge.mm:308)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001c4e2e55c __NSThread__start__ + 808 (NSThread.m:972)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345f69ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345f5e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 8 name:
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fafdaf64 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345fd298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cfa5a4d4 scavenger_thread_main + 1232 (pas_scavenger.c:131)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345f69ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345f5e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 9 name:
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fafdaf64 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345fd298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf9bc5f4 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 1844 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:622)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf85fcd0 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntilUnchecked<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 248 (ParkingLot.h:82)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf983594 WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0, void>::call() + 260 (Condition.h:77)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf9dcf68 WTF::Thread::entryPoint(WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 352 (Function.h:82)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf9df274 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 16 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:242)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345f69ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345f5e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 10 name:
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fafdaf64 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345fd298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf9bc5f4 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 1844 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:622)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf85fcd0 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntilUnchecked<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 248 (ParkingLot.h:82)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf983594 WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0, void>::call() + 260 (Condition.h:77)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf9dcf68 WTF::Thread::entryPoint(WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 352 (Function.h:82)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf9df274 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 16 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:242)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345f69ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345f5e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 11 name:
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fafdaf64 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345fd298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf9bc5f4 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 1844 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:622)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf85fcd0 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntilUnchecked<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 248 (ParkingLot.h:82)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf983594 WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0, void>::call() + 260 (Condition.h:77)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf9dcf68 WTF::Thread::entryPoint(WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 352 (Function.h:82)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf9df274 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 16 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:242)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345f69ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345f5e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 12 name:
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fafdaf64 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345fd298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf9bc5f4 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 1844 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:622)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf85fcd0 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntilUnchecked<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 248 (ParkingLot.h:82)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf983594 WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0, void>::call() + 260 (Condition.h:77)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf9dcf68 WTF::Thread::entryPoint(WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 352 (Function.h:82)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf9df274 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 16 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:242)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345f69ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345f5e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 13 name:
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fafdaf64 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345fd298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf9bc5f4 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 1844 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:622)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf85fcd0 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntilUnchecked<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 248 (ParkingLot.h:82)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf983594 WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0, void>::call() + 260 (Condition.h:77)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf9dcf68 WTF::Thread::entryPoint(WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 352 (Function.h:82)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001cf9df274 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 16 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:242)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345f69ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002345f5e68 thread_start + 8


Thread 4 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x00000001dc3e50f5   x5: 0x000000016d12a430   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000600
    x8: 0x698f0ef5887bab21   x9: 0x698f0ef4e5691b21  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x000000000000000b
   x12: 0x000000000000000b  x13: 0x00000001c39aeaff  x14: 0x00000001dc3e511b  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x000000016d12b000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000001903  x21: 0x000000016d12b0e0  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x000000016d12b0e0
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000281bf84e8  x26: 0x0000000000000114  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x00000002820ff940   fp: 0x000000016d12a3a0   lr: 0x00000002345fc3bc
    sp: 0x000000016d12a380   pc: 0x00000001fafe0b78 cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault


Binary Images:
0x102f00000 - 0x103153fff TeachAssist arm64  <2e694040f60838f6bea38595e9a0aa9d> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/181A550D-D6D7-47C6-AAF9-FC6F91846389/TeachAssist.app/TeachAssist
0x103274000 - 0x1032cbfff dyld arm64e  <d16b72c0d6193e4892622c10a1d3066f> /usr/lib/dyld
0x1c32d5000 - 0x1c331afff libdispatch.dylib arm64e  <69dac9c7ddaf318eb068be596d142a2f> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x1c35d8000 - 0x1c3a2dfff CoreFoundation arm64e  <d2716f2f688b3d51ba8b17e6553b209e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x1c4dc6000 - 0x1c50cefff Foundation arm64e  <feeef9b1b0e63561adfa3ef0302d23f8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x1c5a49000 - 0x1c72e3fff UIKitCore arm64e  <e6e89bb5b5863725bf8f4c85dcd443bd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
0x1ce734000 - 0x1ce7b3fff libsystem_c.dylib arm64e  <b0793d31ed1b3549b86192a10841bf68> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x1ce80c000 - 0x1cfb81fff JavaScriptCore arm64e  <6592b928ee2c3bc2b4e94cdc77022fe0> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x1dc2c0000 - 0x1dc2fcfff libobjc.A.dylib arm64e  <a196a0f6cadb325bbc1f5965e670f9b6> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1dc3d0000 - 0x1dc3e7fff libc++abi.dylib arm64e  <fe24cee611ec3951aa1832594f98ef0d> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x1df690000 - 0x1df698fff GraphicsServices arm64e  <75a910dc87a43b3a8c0ea868b945f5d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x1fafd9000 - 0x1fb00efff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <c2fcc05874803c14b4790064a3f843e3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x2345f5000 - 0x234600fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  <b48efcbed4f7308ba3fa172e0ea78e33> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib

EOF
```

Comment: A crash log like this won't tell you much in a React Native app where the crash is related to the JS code. "I didn't make any significant changes to the app, other than adding 2 small packages and some styling changes." <- sounds like looking at the changes is the place to start.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll take a look at them

Comment: @Ishaan Have you ever fixed this. I am currently having the same problem. But my app never worked in TestFlight.

Comment: @DannyVerdel It was one of the packages I added which only worked on Android and not iOS. I ended up coding that functionality myself  and it worked fine.